# How to get all UIkit Accordions open on load with ReactJS and UIKit?

Tags: reactjs, uikit

I'm building a ReactJS app and using UIkit I'm using the accordion component and I want all of the accordions expanded on page load. I tried to using this piece of code:

```
UIkit.on('afterready.uk.dom', function() {
     var accordion = UIkit.accordion(UIkit.$('#my-accordion'), {collapse:false, showfirst: false});
     accordion.find('[data-wrapper]').each(function () {
         accordion.toggleItem(UIkit.$(this), true, false); // animated true and collapse false
    });
});
```

but I get an error on "UIkit.on", it seems that React cannot find the "UIkit" object.

In my React component I'm importing these:

```
    import 'uikit/js/uikit.js';
    import 'uikit/js/components/accordion.js';
```

I get this error:

> system.src.js:5123 Uncaught (in promise) Error: (SystemJS) SyntaxError: https://localhost/js/components/Facets.js: Unexpected token (23:5) 21 | 22 | > 23 | UIkit.on('afterready.uk.dom', function() { | ^ 24 | var accordion = UIkit.accordion(UIkit.$('#facets'), {collapse:false, showfirst: false}); 25 | accordion.find('[data-wrapper]').each(function () { 26 | accordion.toggleItem(UIkit.$(this), true, false); // animated true and collapse false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being new to both UIkit and ReactJS, I was able to figure out the answer to my question above.

```
UIkit.on('afterready.uk.dom', function() {
 var accordion = UIkit.accordion(UIkit.$('#my-accordion'), {collapse:false, showfirst: false});
 accordion.find('[data-wrapper]').each(function () {
     accordion.toggleItem(UIkit.$(this), true, false); // animated true and collapse false
  });
});
```

This can be placed under:

```
import 'uikit/js/uikit.js';
import 'uikit/js/components/accordion.js';
```

But not inside of

```
export default class NameOfClass extends React.Component {...}
```

Then it works with UIkit that you are importing.